# Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to OPTIONS request

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a project on Google Code, and I am using SVN.

Everything was working fine with that project in Eclipse.

But today I created new project in Google Code. And when trying to add my project from Eclipse to the Google repository which I created it gives an error.

The error in the Eclipse console is:

> svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in
>   response to OPTIONS request for 'https://code.google.com/............'

Eclipse shows this when committing:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKACTIVITY request for '/svn/!svn/act/a5a68afd-6b33-2247-9d70-58e42b6f6f4b'

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKACTIVITY request for '/svn/!svn/act/a5a68afd-6b33-2247-9d70-58e42b6f6f4b'
```

Answer (score 5):

Verify that the Google Code URL has the **HTTPS** protocol and if you are using Subclipse, change to the **svnkit library**.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue by doing what Xorsat said, i.e. check if the Google Code URL is using **HTTPS**. However, I did not have to change anything regarding the **svnkit library**; I'm using the default settings of **Subclipse**, where I installed both Subclipse and the SVNKit plugins in Eclipse.

How do I check if I'm using **HTTPS**?

1. Right click the project
2. Go to *Properties* → *Subversion*

Your **URL** and **Repository Root** should be using **https**.

If you're not using **https**, you must import the project from Google Code again. How?

1. In Eclipse 4.2 (Juno), menu *File* → *Import...*
2. SVN → *Checkout Projects from SVN*, press <kbd>Next</kbd>
3. Check *Create a new repository location*, press <kbd>Next</kbd>
4. In the URL field, copy-paste the **URL** from Google Code; make sure it's using **https**.
5. Select the trunk directory, press <kbd>Next ></kbd>
6. Unless you're sure what you're doing, keep to the default settings, press <kbd>Next ></kbd>
7. Press <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

You should now be able to *Team* → *Commit...* your project! Take note, it'll ask you for your username and googlecode.com password (generated in Google Code Project -> Source).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution: http://www.svnforum.org/threads/35661-Problems-committing-(405-Method-not-allowed)

I tried to drag and drop my file using the repository browser instead of importing the file and it worked for me. By the way I was using [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN).

Comment: The svnforum.org link is (effectively) broken (*"Invalid Page URL"*).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that navigates to this page. I got this error and it turned out that the username for the repository was case sensitive in Eclipse. Typing in the exact correct username solved the issue for me. Hope it helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

For me NONE of the previous worked and will not work ever now. The reason is that Google has deprecated Google Code and will discontinue this service.

It has marked all the projects as "Read ONLY". So you see now why no commits can be made as a repository is READ-ONLY and archived. Go to the Google Code and browse your repository/project, and it will show below message:

> READ-ONLY: This project has been archived. For more information see
>   this post.

Comment: It is even worse now. The result is now "404. That's an error.". Even Google things, like [Google Collections Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/), do not even redirect (same 404 error).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue only to find that my organization's local SVN server was unreachable. May be helpful to some one.